# Export column title in csv

Tags: php, mysql, csv, mysqli, export

I have to improve this code for a better output on my CSV file.
What I need is to export column title too and maybe replace the native column title witha custom values.
Also in csv i have some prices in this form "75.0000", i don't want all that ZERO in the output

```
<?php
$db = new mysqli("server","user","password","db");
        $fp = fopen("list.csv","w");
    if ($rs = $db->query("SELECT column, price, id FROM table,table1 WHERE table.id=table1.id AND table2.id=table.id AND GROUP BY table2.id"))
    {
      while ($row = $rs->fetch_assoc())
      {
        fputcsv($fp, array_values($row));
      }
      $rs->close();
    }
    fclose($fp);
    ?>
```

do you have any suggestion?
Thanks a lot!

I've just edited this part of the code

```
 {
  while ($row = $rs->fetch_assoc()) 
  {
    fputcsv($fp, array_values($map));
    fputcsv($fp, array_values($row));
  }
```

But Now, in the CSV file I have each odd line with the array that I called $map...
Of course, I need it just one time as Header
Thank You

Comment: Just add a line with column title in your code?

Comment: `fetch_assoc`, only to then use `array_values`- :ROLLEYES: ...

Comment: If you want to get the column names from the result set - array_keys(). If you want to “maybe overwrite” them - then specify how that should happen first, where do you want to keep this data. Do you need a dynamic match of statement column name to CSV column title (so that the order inside the statement could be changed later), or is it enough to specify that all as one array of column titles upfront?

Comment: I don't know how to do that, I'm newbie...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I Solved changing the php like this:

```
<?php
include_once('connection.php');
$db = new mysqli("SERVER","USER","PASS","DB");
$date = date('d-M-Y-h-i-s');
$fp = fopen("lista-ordini-$date.csv","w");
$filename = ("lista-ordini-$date.csv");
$map = array("Num Ordine", "Nome", "Data", "Stato", "Prodotto", "SKU", "Prezzo base", "IVA", "Sconto", "Prezzo + IVA", "Totale", "ID");
$query = "SELECT sales_flat_order.increment_id, sales_flat_order_grid.billing_name, sales_flat_order_grid.created_at, sales_flat_order_grid.status, sales_flat_order_item.name, sales_flat_order_item.sku, sales_flat_order_item.base_price,sales_flat_order_item.tax_amount, sales_flat_order_item.discount_amount, sales_flat_order_item.price_incl_tax, sales_flat_order_grid.grand_total, sales_flat_order_grid.entity_id FROM sales_flat_order, sales_flat_order_grid, sales_flat_order_item WHERE sales_flat_order.entity_id=sales_flat_order_grid.entity_id AND sales_flat_order_grid.entity_id=order_id AND sales_flat_order_grid.created_at NOT LIKE '2012%'AND sales_flat_order_grid.created_at NOT LIKE '2013%' GROUP BY entity_id";
$result = mysqli_query($db, $query); 
fputcsv($fp,$map); 
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))  
          {  
               fputcsv($fp, $row);  
          }  
          fclose($fp);  

?>
```

Comment: Now it exports tables with header I need
I hope it will be helpfull fr someone